# How to check if page is restricted from advertising?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook marketing API for creating ads for client pages. But some ads are getting disapproved by FB ads manager because the client page was restricted from advertising. Is it possible to check if a page is restricted from creating ads or the page can't advertise.

I have found a field *promotion_eligible* for [Page Object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/). It says, "Boosted posts eligibility status. Only visible to a page admin". Can we check if the page is restricted from advertising using this flag?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think is a viable method, I am using that same field.